# relative compact implies totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a metric space. It's always true that if $A$ is relative compact (i.e $\bar{A}$ is compact) then $A$ it's also totally bounded?.

I tried to proved it, considering the finite subcovering of $\bar{A}$ of radius $\epsilon>0$ but the problem is that the center points on those balls could live on $\bar{A}-A$ thus it's not necessary true that $A$ is totally bounded. Please help me with this )=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every subset of a totally bounded set is totally bounded. If you work with the definition of total boundedness that doesn't require the centres of the balls to lie in $A$ itself, that is utterly straightforward.

If the centres of the balls are required to lie in $A$, first cover $\overline{A}$ by a finite number of balls $B_1,\, \dotsc,\, B_n$ *of radius* $\varepsilon/2$. In each of these balls, choose an $x_j \in B_j \cap A$ (since we have covered $\overline{A}$, such an $x_j$ exists for all $j$; if we considered a general totally bounded superset of $A$, we would restrict to only the balls that intersect $A$). Then $A$ is covered by the balls $B_\varepsilon(x_j)$ whose centres lie in $A$.